# Filtergraph stops after first data passing

Tags: c++, directshow

Edit: The original problem was that the filtergraph stopped when calling my custom filter. We resolved this by setting the time property of the sample in the deliver method .

I simplified my graph
[image: basic file recorder]

This works fine for recording video to from the webcam to a file.

However if i put my filter in between:

[image]

I get strange results:

[image]

So it looks like it isn't encoded. But without this filter the avi mux hadn't to encode the video fro the webcam either.
Here is the updated deliver method of the outputpin:

```
 HRESULT MCMyOutputPin::Deliver(IMediaSample* sample)
{
    CAutoLock mylock(this->m_pLock);
    HRESULT hr = NO_ERROR;
    myLogger->LogDebug("In Outputpin Deliver", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
    if (sample->GetActualDataLength() > 0)
    {
        IMediaSample *outsample;


        if (!m_pAllocator)
            return E_FAIL;
        hr = m_pAllocator->GetBuffer(&outsample, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            myLogger->LogDebug("Could not get buffer", L"D:\\TEMP\\yc.log");
            return hr;
        }
        BYTE* sampleBuffer = NULL;
        BYTE*  newBuffer = NULL;
        long lSizeSample = sample->GetSize();
        long lSizeOutSample = outsample->GetSize();
        outsample->GetPointer(&newBuffer);
        sample->GetPointer(&sampleBuffer);
        LONGLONG timeStart = NULL;
        LONGLONG timeEnd = NULL;
        REFERENCE_TIME refTime = NULL;
        REFERENCE_TIME reftimeend = NULL;
        sample->GetMediaTime(&timeStart, &timeEnd);
        sample->GetTime(&refTime, &reftimeend);
        ASSERT(lSizeOutSample >= lSizeSample);
        memcpy((void *)newBuffer, (void *)sampleBuffer, lSizeSample);
        outsample->SetMediaTime(&timeStart, &timeEnd);
        outsample->SetTime(&refTime, &reftimeend);
        m_pInputPin->Receive(outsample);







        outsample->Release();
        sample->Release();




    }

    return hr;
    //Forward to filter
}
```

So my question is: if all my filter at the moment does, is to forward samples and not to alter them in anyway, why do i get then this result.

Comment: Are you trying to write two video streams via AVI Mux? I'm not sure it can handle that. And it might cause the graph to stop.

Comment: Now you completely changed the question. Please don't do it, just post a new one.  For the new question: I think the problem is in media type and hence resulting AVI headers. Save two AVI files, one without your filter and one with it. Then look closely at their headers to see the difference. AVIMasterGUI is one very nice tool to do that.

Answer (score 1):

AVI Mux is *very* sensitive to sample media times. In your code I don't see setting proper media times for the sample passed to AVI Mux. Without these times it cannot determine proper frame rate and frame order, so it probably stops.